# Is there any input I can give to scanner that will cause it to crash

Tags: java

I'm working on a fairly simple project that requires the user to respond to prompts in the console. I then harvest the user's input via the java.util.Scanner. Below is a trimmed down version of my code to illustrate the way I get the user's response.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String initialInput = sc.next();
```

I then proceed to use some if/else loops to determine what action the application needs to take based on the String provided. I was wondering if there are any kind of rare case keyboard inputs the user could enter that would cause my application to crash? Currently my if/else loops are like so.

```
     if(initialInput.equals("doJob01")){
        System.out.println("Do Job 1");
     }
     else{
        System.out.println("Application doesn't understand the input");
     }
```

I've tried a number of non-sense bad entries and the application has worked as I expected. Is there anything like "/n" or the like that I haven't thought of that will give me trouble?

Comment: On a unix system, potentially ctrl-D.

Comment: [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) throws an exception if there's no more input or has been closed; is that what you mean?

Comment: `nextInt` will throw an exception is the next token is not an int

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the info, but since we are using next() String in this case I don't think that is something we will need to worry about here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm a little uncertain what you are asking. Are you implying that the user just doesn't type any input? What do you mean closed? The console is closed?